# Active Currency Not Showing Up (Multi-currency enabled, Reports)

Tags: reporting, multi-currency, report-builder, currencytype

Apologies if I am asking a silly question here, but I cannot figure out why my list of currencies (When editing a report -> Preview -> Show -> Currencies Using) does not show all my active currencies in the org.

If I go to Manage Currencies, I see the currencies I need to report on are active, I can also pull them with SOQL queries, however I can't seem to find a way to "update" the list of available currencies for a particular report from the report edit page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you in lightning or classic?  I've never seen that option in classic.

Comment: Found it in classic. Can you add a screenshot of the list that is displayed under report - customize and also the list of active and inactive currencies in your org?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but my problem has been solved! It was very silly actually, for some reason when I use my mouse I could not scroll through the complete list of currencies on the report edit page, but when using the arrow keys I was able to see the full list of active currencies!

Comment: Cool I hadn't seen it before so learned something.  W your mouse you should see a little down arrow at the bottom of the list.  Not very clear.  Glad it's sorted.  You can post your own answer and mark it as best so that others might see it if they run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - It was very silly actually, for some reason when I use my mouse I could not scroll through the complete list of currencies on the report edit page, but when using the arrow keys I was able to see the full list of active currencies!